# jQueryUI.dialog: override single css style property?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

jQuery UI themes are nice they apply to the entire document, however I have some cases where the style of the dialog such as the title bar colour must be changed.

In my jQuery UI css, the titlebar is coded:

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar { padding: .4em 1em; position: relative;  }

Here's my javascript:

```
var $AlertDialog = $('<div"></div>')
.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  title: 'Alert Message',
  buttons: {Ok: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}}
});     

function Alerter(cTxt)
{
  $AlertDialog.html(cTxt);
  $AlertDialog.css('ui-dialog-titlebar','color: red');
  $AlertDialog.dialog('open');
};
```

Alerter() is then called as a substitute for alert().

Accessing and altering the color property of 'ui-dialog-titlebar' has no effect.

Lots of reading preceded this question.  Seems others have had similar issues, but not specific to jQuery UI.

How can this be done?

---

Update:

Thanks to a good hint, I did this:

```
$AlertDialog.dialog('open');
$("#.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('color','red');
$("#.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('background-color','orange');
```

Works.  But acceptable practice?

Comment: Why not add a class and style it with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to not use the .ui-dialog selector as there may be more than one dialog on a page. You can traverse to the title bar.

```
    ...
    $AlertDialog.html(cTxt);
    // might as well use the theme since its part of jquery ui
    $AlertDialog.prev().addClass("ui-state-error");
    $AlertDialog.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) .css() takes property as param.
It seems you are trying changing ui-dialog-titlebar. Instead try this:

```
...
function Alerter(cTxt)
{
  $AlertDialog.html(cTxt);
  $AlertDialog.dialog('open');
  $(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('color','red'); 
  $(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('background-color','orange'); 
  //Assuming you want to change header color only
  //see the theming structure at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#theming
};
```

Comment: $moguzalp You provided a great hint.  Using > span produced an error, but I got it another way.

Comment: $AlertDialog.dialog('open');
$("#.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('color','red');
$("#.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title").css('background-color','orange');